# dynamically change the split layout content GWT

Tags: gwt, layout

I want to change the split layout content dynamically..
The content is text that I take from my database.
So when the user interacts and choose an option in the menu it will change the center's content.

onModule here :

```
   public void onSuccess(List<BibleTxt> result) 
            {
                int i = 0 ;
                String chapterText ="";

                //chapterText = result.get(1).getVerseText();



                for(i=0;i<50;i++)
                    {
                        chapterText = result.get(i).getVerseText();
                        //Label chapterLabel = new Label(chapterText);
                        p.add(new HTML(chapterText));

                    } 

            }
```

Server side :

```
   public List<BibleTxt> getChapterTxt(int book,int chapter) throws Exception
{
    BibleTxt cText = null;
    List<BibleTxt> chapterTxt  = new ArrayList<BibleTxt>();
    Connection conn = null;
    PreparedStatement pstmt = null;
    ResultSet result = null;

    try{
        conn = getConnection();
        pstmt = conn.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM bibledb_kjv WHERE BOOKID = ? AND CHAPTERNO =  ?");
        pstmt.setInt(1,book);
        pstmt.setInt(2,chapter);
        result = pstmt.executeQuery();
        //cText = new BibleTxt();
        int i=0;
        while (result.next()) 
            {
                cText = new BibleTxt(result.getInt("BOOKID"), result.getInt("CHAPTERNO"), result.getString("VERSETEXT"));
                chapterTxt.add(i, cText);
            //  ((ResultSet) cText.getChapterList()).next();
                i++;



            }

    }
```

The text id divided by verses in database. and I want to display for example all verses of book 1 chapter 1.

Comment: Can you be more elaborate. You can change the center's content anytime you want. Try to put some code, so that we can understand what you are trying to do

Answer (score 0):

I believe `p` is your split panel. You cannot use api `p.add()` more than once. You have to use `addEast/West/North/South` depending on your requirements.

Comment: yup, I created a paragraph using simplePanel and insert it to an HTML object then added it to "p" and it worked.
I don't know how to use these split layouts...
if you have more complicated example than the google declaration examples please post a link ! thank you

Comment: You will not get complex examples on the web. If I get time, I will post it here.